# How to change the tips of the 2-cells in xy-pic?

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I used the `cmtip` option in xypic, but this doesn't change the tips of the `\xtwocells`, and I have a lot of 2-cells. I am using `cmtip` because I want the tips in the diagrams to match the ones of the in-line arrows `$A\to B$`. It seems that the `cmtip` option is not compatible with the `2cell` option. So how to change the tips of the 2-cells?

If this leads to also put any symbol (which can be oriented properly) in the place of the 2-cell. I would also like to know about that.

Here is a simple example. A square with a cell inside.

```
\documentclass{article}% 
\usepackage[all,2cell,cmtip]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells
\begin{document}
\[
\vcenter{\hbox{\xymatrix@!0@=15mm{
tl\ar[r]^-{t}\ar[d]_-{l}\xtwocell[rd]{}<>{2}&tr\ar[d]^-{r}\\
bl\ar[r]_-{b}&br
}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: lax square]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

$$\xymatrix{
tl\ar[r]^t \ar[d]_l &tr\ar[d]^r\ar@{=>}[ld]^2\\
bl\ar[r]_b &br
}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Avoid using $$ in LaTeX, `\[....\]` is better.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately if I compile it as you wrote, it doesn't change the tip of the 2-cell. From your code I was not expecting this behaviour.

Also, the 2cell is way too long, I prefer the shorter one as in the example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Is a solution with `tikz-cd` Ok for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        tl\ar{r}{t} \ar{d}[swap]{l} &tr \arrow[Rightarrow]{ld}{2}\arrow{d}{r} \\
        bl\ar{r}[swap]{b} &br
    \end{tikzcd}
    \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really, I have a long document with many many diagrams that include 2cells, some of them quite complicated. But thanks.

Comment: @RamónAbudAlcalá Sorry, I can't help you with `xymatrix`. Perhaps if you add to your question one of your complex diagram someone else can understand better your problem and solve it.

Comment: well the question is not about any particular diagram, is about the possibility to change the tips of the 2-cells of xy-pic. So that my document has a uniform look.